# vscode: fastest way to set the windows' sizes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode to code and I open usually one, two or three windows.

When I open only one window, it will fill in the whole interface of vscode.

When I open another one or two windows, they will seperate the interface equally, which is not what I expected.

I want to get a way to resize two or three windows fast.

For example, if there are two windows, I want the width of the first window to be 300 and the second to be 200. And if there are three windows, I want their widths to be 150, 150 and 200. Of course, these numbers are simply an example because the max width isn't 500. But I always make my vscode maximized so fixed numbers would be fine to me.

When I open the second or the third window, I have to resize them with the mouse everytime, this is kind of boring. Is there any better way to resize the windows?

For example, if there are two or three windows, vscode can resize them automatically? Or some shortcuts to resize two or three windows?